# How to fix "nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke" (console)

Tags: ios, network-framework

I'm configuring a new Firebase app in Xcode, but get "nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C1] Receive reply failed with error 'Operation canceled'" printed repeatedly in the console. What should I do to fix this?

This is in Xcode 11 Beta 3, and I've tried creating a new project altogether since the original was created from an older version of Xcode, yet I still get this error printed repeatedly in the console even though all I've done is run it once after configuring.

I expect to see no errors in the console, yet this error is printed many times.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413646/backgroundtask-ios-13-swift

Comment: I get the same message (for several betas now) from a straightforward URLSession call. I've come to the conclusion it's a beta related informational message that has yet to be cleaned up.

Comment: @JimMarquardt well, still the same error more than a month later, with Xcode 11 GM  2

Comment: This is still exist in released version of Xcode 11.

Comment: Having same issue here. The console shows these messages after `navigationController.pop`.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Xcode 11.1

Comment: Getting this on xcode 12 beta on a URLSession, still seems to work OK.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. My code looked like this:

```
UserServices().getUserWithUID(uid: user.uid) { (user) in
    self.window?.rootViewController = MapViewController(user: user)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

All I did to resolve the problem was change my code to this:

```
let userServices = UserServices()
userServices.getUserWithUID(uid: user.uid) { (user) in
    self.window?.rootViewController = MapViewController(user: user)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

and the console errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that this popped up, after I inserted a password, that had less characters. Somehow Firebase needs minimum six letters and I tried to use three.